# OData: How long does SO data take to become available?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was getting some really odd results from the featured queries on http://odata.stackexchange.com so I decided to run a basic table dump.

```
declare @UserId int = ##UserId##

select * from posts where OwnerUserId = @UserID​ order by Creation​Date​
```

It lists my last post as coming from 2010-10-27! The `comments` table has the same issue.

Does it take some number of weeks for data to become available? Or is this just me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data load process is still manual, so it takes time, usually 6-8... days after the end of the month.

We get asked this question every month, and IIRC from last month, @waffles is looking to automate the data loading. Hopefully he does it soon as the number of sites being put in the data dump is only going to be increasing.

Comment: @waffles what's the status on this? odata/StackOverflow data is again one month old. That makes the site pretty worthless

Comment: @waffles: it's still month old :)

Comment: @Giedrius: Sorry, this answer is old. I think the data loads are once every two months now (haven't been keeping up with it).